# Which branch of mathematics studies the parameters of logical problems?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Suppose I have the following problem:

$2$   kids are liars, $3$ can only say the truth.

Julia: "Jack is only a liar, if John is telling the truth

Jack: "If Joey doesn't lie, then either Julia or John do

Joey: "Jane lies, as does Julia or Jack.

John: "If Jack is telling the truth, then Julia or Joey do as well

Jane: "If you round up Julia, Joey, and John, you will have at least one liar." Who are the compulsive liars?

Now before giving this problem to somebody else, I have to make sure that I have given enough information for this problem to be solved, and that none of my information is contradictory.  Is there a systematic way of constructing such problems and if so what branch of maths deals with this?

Comment: Propositional logic.

Comment: Are there any good books  that you would recommend?

Comment: Many... you can start with Raymond Smullyan, [Logical Labyrinths](http://logic-books.info/sites/default/files/logical_labirints.pdf), AK Peters (2009) and Valentin Goranko, [Logic as a Tool : A Guide to Formal Logical Reasoning](https://books.google.it/books?id=R687CwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover), Wiley (2016).

Comment: I would look into 'Book of Proof' by Richard Hammack, made available freely online by the author and offers a nice introduction to propositional logic and set theory, which are then applied to study the various proof techniques employed in mathematics.